# pipenv ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'datetime'" after reinstalling Python

Tags: windows-10, python, pip, django

I had recently tried reinstalling Python, and after Python was installed successfully, after activating my virtual environment using `pipenv shell` whenever I try to run `python manage.py` I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\moaha\.virtualenvs\restapi-Ks1Qcdgf\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>     
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "C:\Users\moaha\.virtualenvs\restapi-Ks1Qcdgf\lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datetime'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a 
virtual environment?
```

Python on its own works fine, and `pipenv` also works (activates the environment properly), and I've tried to run updates on `pip` and `pipenv`. I'm not really sure what is going on and how to fix this issue.

Heres how my Environment Variables > Path look like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\
```

Also, sometimes I get a `runpy` error, not sure if it is related in anyway. However, I am unable to replicate the `runpy` issue.

I sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to "solve" (I guess it's more like a hack job?) this issue by going into the `.virtualenvs` folder, located in `C:\Users\<user>\.virtualenvs`, and deleting all the project folders that had the issue, and use the `> pipenv shell` followed by `> pipenv install` to install all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. =)